# Remainder Theorem co

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In this screenshot: https://gyazo.com/5052812379fedee11586ea1db3d55b78
It states "As the divisor is a linear expression and F(X) is a cubic polynomial then Q(X) must be a quadratic and the remainder must be **a constant**.

I don't understand how they determined it would be a constant by that information.

Answer (score 0):

For  Euclidean division in polynomial rings, the condition for the remainder $R(x)$ is ‘$R(x)=0$ or $\deg R(x)<\deg(\text{divisor})$’.

Here, for a linear divisor, it says the remainder is $0$ or has degree $0$, i.e. is a constant.

Comment: Alright, just to clarify because I'm not the best at Math.                                                  The degree of the remainder always has to be less than the degree of the divisor? Does this mean if I had a Quadratic divisor, I could chose for it to be linear or a constant? This is probably wrong lol

Comment: Not at lol. It maybe a constant or a linear polynomial, but it's not at your will: the remainder and the quotient are unique, up to a non-zero constant factor.